# phpmyadmin エラーコード200への対処法について

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

wordpressのローカル環境を構築するためにxamppをインストールしてphpmyadminにログインしたところ、下記のようなポップアップが表示され、DBが作成できません。

要求処理中でのエラー
エラーコード：200
エラーテキスト：OK
ネットワーク接続が失われているようです。接続状況とサーバーの状態を確認してください。
[image: yad]

エラーログを確認しましたがエラー文言は見つからず、
どのように調査すればよいのかもわからないため、わかる方いましたら教えていただけたら幸いです。

Comment: エラーログとはMySQLのエラーログとApacheのエラーログがありますが、どちらも確認されていますか？

Answer (score 0):

同じ現象が発生しました。ブラウザをedgeに変えてphpmyadminにログインしたらうまく行きました。
現象が発生したのはchromeです。

Answer (score 0):

ブラウザを変えたことで解消できたと言うことであれば、MySQLのバージョンにphpMyAdminが対応していない問題ではないかと思います。
ブラウザを変えてもエラーが解消できない場合は、phpMyAdmin4.8系がMySQL5.5以降に対応しているlc_messageオプションが原因です。